# Using godaddy how to use header("Location:URL")

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my localhost this page redirection working properly but when I setup my project on Godaddy hosting site it doesn't redirect to page it actually displaying same page! 
My code is as below:

```
<?
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');

$news_id=$_GET["id"];
$m_id=$_GET["m_id"];
$category =$_GET["category"];

$res=mysqli_query($con,"delete from marathi where id=$news_id");
if($res<=0)
{
    $_SESSION["MSG"]="News not deleted, Try Again";
    header("Location: m_news.php?id=".$m_id."&name=".$category);    
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["MSG"]="News deleted";
    header("Location: m_news.php?id=".$m_id."&name=".$category);    
}
?>
```

When I use godaddy this line is not working ..

> header("Location: m_news.php?id=".$m_id."&name=".$category);

Comment: Enable error reporting. I'll bet you see a "headers already sent" error.

Comment: ok so how to resolve this type of error..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/476

Comment: Is this printing full php script code?

Comment: it actually displays nothing ...

Comment: Did you enable error reporting?

Comment: NO! It not executing header("Location :  xxx"); code

Comment: You mean other code is runnung? just add die('hello); after include and check this prints or not

Comment: after adding die(); it start redirecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117689/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-deepak-dholiyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always add a `die()` call after issuing Location headers.

The HTTP response must be terminated without any body data for browsers to properly interpret the redirect headers, if you just run your `header()` and let the PHP script continue there is no guarantee that the body of the response will be empty and if it isn't the redirect will not work.

```
header("Location: m_news.php?id=".$m_id."&name=".$category);
die(); // Stop further execution and prevent any accidental output.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good practice to add die(); after every redirect. This stops execution of next script.

```
 header("Location: m_news.php?id=".$m_id."&name=".$category);
 die();
```